# What is the event of a DataGridView for 'Highlighting a Row Number'

Tags: c#

I have populated a datagrid but would like an event to fire when the user double clicks the row and highlights it. I have looked through all the properties but cannot seem to work out which one it is.

I've also looked on MSDN but also cannot see anything.

Many Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Not sure what you actually mean by 'rownumber', but there is the [SelectionChanged](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+datagridview+SelectionChanged+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) event you can code to check what rows if any are selected now.. Keep an eye on the [SelectionMode](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+datagridview+SelectionMode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: I tried that but that does it on a cell basis and also fires when I populate the datagrid. Plus I want it for a DoubleClick option not single. I have amended my question.

Comment: @taw I thought an event for row highlighting would be pretty standard...

Comment: Well you can also code the `RowStateChanged` event and test the new state for `DataGridViewElementStates.Selected`. But you also wanted several additional conditions, remember like doublclicking and something funny about row numbers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to use the code below:**

```
this.dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);

private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed. I will mark as answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `CellDoubleClick` is it won't fire an event for keyboard users when navigating with arrows.

Instead, some other events you can handle are:

- [`RowEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter)
- [`SelectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`RowStateChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowstatechanged)

You can poke around when each fires by attaching handlers to each event and writing to the output window:

```cs
dataGridView1.RowEnter += dgv_RowEnter;
dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += dgv_SelectionChanged;
dataGridView1.RowStateChanged += dgv_RowStateChanged;
dataGridView1.CellContentClick += dgv_CellContentClick;

private void dgv_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RowEnter");
}

private void dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("SelectionChanged");
}

private void dgv_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RowStateChanged");
}

private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("CellContentClick");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not required now but helpful.